# Why are arguments to replacement functions not evaluated lazily?

Tags: r, promise

Consider the following simple function:

```
f <- function(x, value){print(x);print(substitute(value))}
```

Argument `x` will eventually be evaluated by `print`, but `value` never will. So we can get results like this:

```
> f(a, a)  
Error in print(x) : object 'a' not found  
> f(3, a)  
[1] 3  
a  
> f(1+1, 1+1)  
[1] 2  
1 + 1  
> f(1+1, 1+"one")  
[1] 2  
1 + "one"
```

Everything as expected.

Now consider the same function body in a replacement function:

```
'g<-' <- function(x, value){print(x);print(substitute(value))}
```

(the single quotes should be fancy quotes)

Let's try it:

```
> x <- 3  
> g(x) <- 4  
[1] 3  
[1] 4
```

Nothing unusual so far...

```
> g(x) <- a  
Error: object 'a' not found
```

This is unexpected. Name `a` should be printed as a language object.

```
> g(x) <- 1+1  
[1] 4  
1 + 1
```

This is ok, as `x`'s former value is `4`. Notice the expression passed unevaluated.

The final test:

```
> g(x) <- 1+"one"  
Error in 1 + "one" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Wait a minute... Why did it try to evaluate this expression?

Well the question is: bug or feature? What is going on here? I hope some guru users will shed some light about promises and lazy evaluation on R. Or we may just conclude it's a bug.

Comment: I'm probably missing something really fundamental, but it seems to me that both your functions behave in exactly the same way. When you all `f(a, a)` you get an error message that you expect. When you call `g(x) <- a` you get exactly the same error message but you don't expect it. Why is this?

Comment: I think the problem is with what you think the interpreter is actually doing.  Notice that `'g<-'(x, 1+"one")` works

Comment: The first error message comes from `print(x)`, not from `print(substitute(value))`. The point is: `a` is not defined. In the second call to `f`, the symbol `a` is ok even if undefined, and gets printed as a language object. Compare with the call `g(x) <- a`.

Comment: @Dason, so this means that `g(x) <- y` is not equivalent to `y <- 'g<-'(x,y)`. Why not? What else takes place when we use the replacement function as in the first call?

Comment: It may be because when R parses `g(x) <- a` to transform it into `"g<-"(x,a)`, it then evaluates `a` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the key may be found in this comment beginning at [line 1682 of `"eval.c"`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/eval.c#L1682) (and immediately followed by the evaluation of the assignment operation's RHS):

```
/* It's important that the rhs get evaluated first because
assignment is right associative i.e. a <- b <- c is parsed as
a <- (b <- c). */

PROTECT(saverhs = rhs = eval(CADR(args), rho));
```

We expect that if we do `g(x) <- a <- b <- 4 + 5`, both `a` and `b` will be assigned the value `9`; this is in fact what happens.

Apparently, the way that R *ensures* this consistent behavior is to always evaluate the RHS of an assignment first, before carrying out the rest of the assignment. If that evaluation fails (as when you try something like `g(x) <- 1 + "a"`), an error is thrown and no assignment takes place.

Comment: The quoted block above is from `applydefine`, which is called by `do_set` (which implements `<-`, `=`, and `<<-`). As I read it, `applydefine` gets called when the LHS is a language object (like `g(x)` but not when it's a name object (like `x`). See in particular lines 1844 and 1869 of `"eval.c"`. Could some C-literate type please confirm whether my interpretation's correct?

Comment: things get even funnier when we use chained assignements:  
`> 'g<-' <- function(x, value){substitute(value)}`  
`> g(x) <- 1+1`  
`> x`  
`1 + 1`  
`> mode(x)`  
`[1] "call"`  
`> y <- g(x) <- 1+1`  
`> x`  
`1 + 1`  
`> mode(x)`  
`[1] "call"`  
`> y`  
`[1] 2`  
`> mode(y)`  
`[1] "numeric"`

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft -- Or even this: `'g<-' <- function(x, value){deparse(substitute(value))}; x <- 0; y <- g(x) <- 100 + 100; y; x`. It makes good sense to me that `x` gets the value it does, but I'm still not sure I'm seeing the order in which all of the pieces get evaluated. It almost looks like `<- 1+1` gets parsed and evaluated twice, once as the RHS of `g(x) <- 1 + 1`, and once as the RHS of the RHS of `y <- g(x) <- 1 + 1` (if that makes sense). In any case, thanks for the fascinating question!

Comment: I believe I've figured out what is going on here. The assignment expression `g(x) <- 1+1` has a *result* which is the evaluation of the RHS, regardless of what the function `'g<-'` does. Try, for instance, a dummy function `'g<-' <- function(x, value){0}`. Then enter `(g(x) <- 1+1) == 2`. This explains why `g(x) <- 1+"one"` triggers an error. It's not because the RHS is being evaluated *inside* the function, but it's being evaluated outside, by the assignement function itself, which must return this value just in case it's a chain of assignments. If it is not, the result is simply thrown away.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, when you write `y <- g(x) <- 100 + 100`, do you expect (just like me) that `y` is assigned the same value `x` is? See my comment above. I believe this is a wrong assumption. `y` is being assigned the *result* of `g(x) <- 100 + 100`, which is the RHS *regardless* of what the function `'g<-'` returns. A more pedestrian example is: `w <- 42; wn <- names(w) <- "Answer"`. `wn` will receive only the character vector.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft -- I think we basically agree. I never expected `y` to get the same value as `x` does: `x` isn't even on the chain of assignments, and only gets modified by `g<-`. Phenomenologically, I also agree that there's *something* like what you call a *result* which gets passed on down the chain. I'm mostly just curious how that's implemented, but without learning a bunch more C, curious I'll have to stay!

Answer (score 12):

We can reduce the problem to a slightly simpler example:

```
g <- function(x, value)
'g<-' <- function(x, value) x
x <- 3

# Works
g(x, a)
`g<-`(x, a)

# Fails
g(x) <- a
```

This suggests that R is doing something special when evaluating a replacement function: I suspect it evaluates all arguments. I'm not sure why, but the comments in the C code (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/eval.c#L1656 and https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/eval.c#L1181) suggest it may be to make sure other intermediate variables are not accidentally modified.

Luke Tierney has a long comment about the drawbacks of the current approach, and illustrates some of the more complicated ways replacement functions can be used:

> There are two issues with the approach here:
>
> A complex assignment within a complex assignment, like
>   `f(x, y[] <- 1) <- 3`, can cause the value temporary
>   variable for the outer assignment to be overwritten and
>   then removed by the inner one.  This could be addressed by
>   using multiple temporaries or using a promise for this
>   variable as is done for the RHS.  Printing of the
>   replacement function call in error messages might then need
>   to be adjusted.
>
> With assignments of the form `f(g(x, z), y) <- w` the value
>   of `z` will be computed twice, once for a call to `g(x, z)`
>   and once for the call to the replacement function `g<-`.  It
>   might be possible to address this by using promises.
>   Using more temporaries would not work as it would mess up
>   replacement functions that use substitute and/or
>   nonstandard evaluation (and there are packages that do
>   that -- igraph is one).

Comment: Glad you started to dig on this one.  Would you have a look at my answer, and let me know what you think?

Comment: @hadley both of the line number references seem to be out of date :( any chance you know which comments were targeted? I still see Luke's quote you cite in there

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, so please, folks with more knowledge feel free to comment/edit.

Note that when you run

```
'g<-' <- function(x, value){print(x);print(substitute(value))}
x <- 1
g(x) <- 5
```

a side effect is that 5 is assigned to `x`. Hence, both must be evaluated. But if you then run

```
'g<-'(x,10)
```

both the values of `x` and 10 are printed, but the value of `x` remains the same.

**Speculation:**

So the parser is distinguishing between whether you call `g<-` in the course of making an actual assignment, and when you simply call `g<-` directly.

Comment: Does the value of `x` following `g(x) <- 1 + 1` -- it's not `2` -- undermine this hypothesis? It *looks* like in this case, the RHS is assigned but not evaluated.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Well, it certainly strongly implies that I'm not seeing the whole picture, that's fer damn sure. Maybe `1+1` can be evaluated because it involves no object look-ups...?

Comment: Well, you're definitely on the right track, I think. For a parallel piece of evidence, compare `e1 <- parse(text="g(x) <- 1 + 'a'"); e2 <- parse(text="'g<-'(x, 1 + 'a')"); as.list(e1[[1]]); as.list(e2[[1]])`. My strong guess is that we won't make much more progress on this without delving into the C-level implementation of `<-` and the `REPL`.

Comment: One thing is that the the equivalent of `g(x) = 5` is `x = 'g<-'(x, 5)`. Also `print(substitute(value))` is returning `substitute(value)`, i.e., the parse tree for the unevaluated expression. On the other hand `'g<-'= function(x, value) value` would force the evaluation of value. Also, the key players are the first and last values, so `'g<-' = function(x, ..., value) value` is the usual 'replacement' paradigm. maybe used like `'g<-' = function(x, FUN, ..., value) FUN(value)` and `g(x, abs) = -2` vs `g(x, sqrt) =  2`